# C++ Return sprite object from class in vector

Tags: c++, sfml

I have an Entity baseclass which the classes Player and Enemy Inherit. Both player and enemy contain a sprite object (From the SFML api) that looks like this:

```
class Player : Entity
{
   sf::Sprite sprite
}
```

Player and Enemy are created inside a vector which is set up like this:

```
class EntityManager
{
   public:
   void CollisionCheck();
   private:
   std::vector<Entity*> entityVector;
}
```

I'm looking to use a collision detection function which is of this form:

```
bool Collision::CircleTest(const sf::Sprite& Object1, const sf::Sprite& Object2)
```

So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
void EntityManager::ColCheck()
{
   if (Collision::CircleTest(entityVector[0].sprite, entityVector[1].sprite))
      {
         cout << "COLLISION\n";
      }
}
```

But I get this compile error:

error: request for member ‘sprite’ in

> ‘((EntityManager*)this)->EntityManager::entityVector.std::vector<_Tp,
>   _Alloc>::operator[] with _Tp = Entity*, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator’, which
>   is of non-class type ‘Entity*’

How do I pass the sprite object from these classes inside the vector to the collision function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `entityVector` holds `Entity*` you'll need to use the proper syntax: `entityVector[0]->sprite` instead of `entityVector[0].sprite`.

Comment: I'm now getting a problem with 'error: ‘class Entity’ has no member named ‘sprite’'

Previously I had 'Class Entity {Sf::Sprite sprite}' and so my code would compile, but it meant that the sprite of the inherited object was never accessed. I am unsure how to create a dummy sprite in Entity so that the method above works?

Comment: sf::Sprite is a class from the SFML api, so i'm unsure how i'd make it a member of Entity baseclass. Your comment did make sense though, and is much appreciated.

Comment: `class Entity{sf::Sprite sprite;}; class Player : public Entity{};`

Comment: That works perfectly, the problem was that I had Sf:Sprite sprite inside both entity and Player. Once I removed it from Player it worked. Thank you very much!